# calling float array from another class

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, class

Noob question here.

If I have Class A with an array float itemsPosition[20][20] and I have another class B to access that, how can I do it?

What I usually do it to alloc Class A and access for other objects but in this case, I can't synthesize float array within Class A.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you synthesize? How about using a setter?

Comment: I think because float is not an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `@synthesize` an `NSValue` that holds a pointer to your array.

```
@interface SomeObject : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSValue *itemsPosition;
@end

@implementation SomeObject
@synthesize itemsPosition;
...
static float anArray[20][20];
...
- (void) someMethod
{
    ... add items to the array
    [self setItemsPosition:[NSValue valueWithPointer:anArray]];
}
@end

@implementation SomeOtherObject
...
- (void) someOtherMethod
{
    SomeObject *obj = [[SomeObject alloc] init];
    ...
    float (*ary2)[20] = (float(*)[20])[obj.itemsPosition pointerValue];
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 to you too... NSValues are a very elegant, very Objective C way to solve this problem as well.

Comment: Never knew about NSValues! Great! Will try this

Comment: You'd just change the lowest size of the array declaration. `float (*ary2)[10] = (float(*)[10])[obj.itemsPosition pointerValue];`

Answer (score 1):

Floats are C-types and so you can't use the typical Objective C property thing to access them directly.

Best thing to do is create an "accessor" function that gives class B access to the pointer for the very first array entry "`itemsPosition`".  E.G. "`itemsPosition[0][0]`"

In class A's .h file:

```
float itemsPosition[20][20];

- (float *) getItemsPosition;
```

and in the .m file:

```
- (float *) getItemsPosition
{
    // return the location of the first item in the itemsPosition 
    // multidimensional array, a.k.a. itemsPosition[0][0]
    return( &itemsPosition[0][0] );
}
```

And in class B, since you know the size of this multidimensional array is 20 x 20, you can step to the location of the next array entry pretty easily:

```
    float * itemsPosition = [classA getItemsPosition];
    for(int index = 0; index < 20; index++)
    {
        // this takes us to to the start of itemPosition[index]
        float * itemsPositionAIndex = itemsPosition+(index*20);

        for( int index2 = 0; index2 < 20; index2++)
        {
            float aFloat = *(itemsPositionAIndex+index2);
            NSLog( @"float %d + %d is %4.2f", index, index2, aFloat);
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if it would be useful for me to put a sample Xcode project up for you somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried this but I returned itemsPosition instead of &itemsPosition. Will try this out!